# Update if count is greater than zero otherwise don't do anything

Tags: sql, postgresql

I have two queries, first is a check if value exists in `table1`, if yes - I'm updating a value in `table2`, otherwise I return 0 as a count of found values.

It happens really often and I wish I could do that with one query. How would the query look like then?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe you can try something like this. A `RETURNING` clause will return  rows if at least one row was updated in the `with` clause. It is then verified by an `exists` check in the `select` part.

```
with upd as
( 
  update table2 t2 set col = 'value4'  
    where id = ? and exists ( select 1 from table1 t1 where id = ?  ) returning *
 ) 
 select  exists ( select 1 from upd ) :: int as "updated";
```

This query when run will return `0` ( integer equivalent of  boolean `false` )  when no rows exist and `1` when at least one row was updated.

[**DEMO**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=608c65a355a889d5bf7de26f9a5eb339)

Answer (score 1):

You can join table1 & table2 and then update the value from table2 with table1.

Comment: so if row with given id doesn't exist in main table - it won't apply any changes in the end?

Comment: yes, if you use inner join then it will return only the the records those are present in both the tables. then you can directly update it.